# Salesforce: How to get fields of two objects "Account" and "Contact" on visualforce page using Backbone.js?

Tags: html, backbone.js, salesforce, visualforce

I am successfull to get "Contact" sobject fields on visualforce page using backbone.js. I want to show both account and contact fields at same time and same page. To do this, should i use two models for each object, or two collections for each object. If yes, then please explain a little bit. Kindly guide me as i am new to backbone.js. Here is my code.

```
 <apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 
  <title>Contacts in Backbone.js</title>

  <!-- ========= -->
  <!--    CSS    -->
  <!-- ========= -->
  <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.MobileSample_Resources_Backbone, 'resources/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css')}" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- ========= -->
  <!-- Libraries -->
  <!-- ========= -->
  <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MobileSample_Resources_Backbone, 'resources/lib/jquery-2.0.0.min.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MobileSample_Resources_Backbone, 'resources/lib/underscore-1.4.4.min.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MobileSample_Resources_Backbone, 'resources/lib/backbone-1.0.0.min.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MobileSample_Resources_Backbone, 'resources/lib/forcetk.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MobileSample_Resources_Backbone, 'resources/lib/force.entity.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    $( document ).on( "mobileinit",
      // Set up the "mobileinit" handler before including jQuery Mobile
      function() {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
      }
    )
  </script>
  <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.MobileSample_Resources_Backbone, 'resources/lib/jquerymobile.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- ========= -->
  <!-- HTML CODE -->
  <!-- ========= -->
  <div id="contacts" data-role="page" data-title="Contacts">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Contacts</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" id="contacts-content">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="contact" data-role="page" data-title="Contact">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href='#' id="back" class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l'>Back</a>
        <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" id="contact-content">
    </div>
  </div>

   <!-- ========= -->
  <!-- Templates -->
  <!-- ========= -->
  <script type="text/template" id="contacts-template">
    <form>
        <button data-role="button" class="new">New Contact</button>
    </form>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="contact-list">
    </ul>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="select-theme" class="select">UI Theme:</label>
        <select class="theme-selector" name="select-theme" id="select-theme">
          <option value="default">default</option>
          <option value="a">a</option>
          <option value="b">b</option>
          <option value="c">c</option>
          <option value="d">d</option>
          <option value="e">e</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/template" id="contact-template">
    <% if (typeof(Id) !== 'undefined') { %>
      <a href="#<%= Id %>"><%- Name %></a> 
    <% } else { %>
      <%- Name %>
    <% } %>
  </script>

  <script type="text/template" id="contact-detail-template">
    <form name="contactform" id="contactform">
      <% if (typeof(Id) !== 'undefined') { %>
        <input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" value="<%- Id %>" />
      <% } %>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="Name">First Name:</label>
        <% if (typeof(FirstName) !== 'undefined') { %>
          <input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="<%- FirstName %>" />
        <% } else { %>
          <input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" />
        <% } %>
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="Name">Last Name:</label>
        <% if (typeof(LastName) !== 'undefined') { %>
          <input name="LastName" id="LastName" value="<%- LastName %>" />
        <% } else { %>
          <input name="LastName" id="LastName" />
        <% } %>
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="Email">Email:</label>
        <% if (typeof(Email) !== 'undefined') { %>
          <input name="Email" id="Email" value="<%- Email %>" />
        <% } else { %>
          <input name="Email" id="Email" />
        <% } %>
      </div>
      <button data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" class="save">Save</button>
      <% if (typeof(Id) !== 'undefined') { %>
        <button data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-inline="true" class="destroy">Delete</button>
      <% } %>
    </form>
  </script>

  <!-- =============== -->
  <!-- Javascript code -->
  <!-- =============== -->
  <script type="text/javascript">


    function changeTheme(theme){
      var hfTheme = theme, 
          cTheme = theme;

      if (theme === 'default') {
        // "If no theme swatch letter is set at all, the framework uses the 
        // "a" swatch (black in the default theme) for headers and footers 
        // and the "c" swatch (light gray in the default theme) for the page 
        // content to maximize contrast between the both."
        // http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/themes.html
        hfTheme = "a";
        cTheme = "c";
      }

      $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-btn').not('.ui-li-divider')
                         .removeClass('ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-up-d ui-btn-up-e ui-btn-hover-a ui-btn-hover-b ui-btn-hover-c ui-btn-hover-d ui-btn-

hover-e')
                         .addClass('ui-btn-up-' + cTheme)
                         .attr('data-theme', cTheme);

      $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-li-divider').each(function (index, obj) {
        if ($(this).parent().attr('data-divider-theme') == 'undefined') {
            $(this).removeClass('ui-bar-a ui-bar-b ui-bar-c ui-bar-d ui-bar-e')
                   .addClass('ui-bar-' + cTheme)
                   .attr('data-theme', cTheme);
        }
      })

      $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-header, .ui-footer')
                         .removeClass('ui-bar-a ui-bar-b ui-bar-c ui-bar-d ui-bar-e')
                         .addClass('ui-bar-' + hfTheme)
                         .attr('data-theme', hfTheme);
      $.mobile.activePage.removeClass('ui-body-a ui-body-b ui-body-c ui-body-d ui-body-e')
                         .addClass('ui-body-' + cTheme)
                         .attr('data-theme', cTheme);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var creds = {
        accessToken: '{!$Api.Session_ID}'
      };

      Force.init(creds);

      myapp();
    });

    function myapp() {
      var app = {}; // create namespace for our app

      //--------------
      // Models
      //--------------
      app.Contact = Force.SObject.extend({
        sobjectType:'Contact',
        fieldlist:['Id', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email']
      });

      //--------------
      // Collections
      //--------------
      app.ContactsCollection = Force.SObjectCollection.extend({
        model: app.Contact,
        fieldlist:['Id', 'Name', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email'],
        config: function() {
          return {type:"soql", query:"SELECT " + this.fieldlist.join(",") + " FROM Contact ORDER BY Name LIMIT 25"};
        }
      }),

      //--------------
      // Views
      //--------------

      // renders individual Contact list item (li)
      app.ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: _.template($('#contact-template').html()),
        render: function(){
          this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
          return this; // enable chained calls
        },
        initialize: function(){
        }
      });

      // renders individual Contact for editing
      app.ContactDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#contact-detail-template').html()),
        render: function(){
          this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
          return this; // enable chained calls
        },
        initialize: function(){
          this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
          this.render();
        },
        events: {
          'change' : 'change',
          'click .save' : 'save',
          'click .destroy': 'destroy'
        },
        change: function (event) {
            // Apply the change to the model
            var target = event.target;
            var change = {};
            change[target.name] = target.value;
            this.model.set(change);
        },
        save: function(){
          this.model.save(null, {
            success: function(model) {
              app.router.navigate('contacts', {trigger: true});
            },
            error: function () {
              alert('Error saving');
            }
          });
          return false;
        },
        destroy: function(){
          this.model.destroy({
            success: function() {
              app.router.navigate('contacts', {trigger: true});             
            },
              error: function () {
                alert('Error deleting');
              }
          });
          return false;
        }
      });

      // renders the full list of Contacts calling ContactView for each one.
      app.ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#contacts-template').html()),
        initialize: function() {
          this.render();
          this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
          this.model.on('reset', this.render, this);
        },
        events: {
          'click .new' : 'newContact',
          'change .theme-selector' : 'changeTheme'
        },
        renderOne: function(contact){
          var view = new app.ContactView({model: contact});
          this.$('#contact-list').append(view.render().el);
        },
        render: function(){
          this.$el.html(this.template());
          this.$('#contact-list').empty();
          for (var i = 0, l = this.model.models.length; i < l; i++) {
            this.renderOne(this.model.models[i]);
          }
        },
        changeTheme: function(event){
          event.preventDefault();

          var theme = $(event.target).children("option").filter(":selected").text();

          changeTheme(theme);
        },
        newContact: function(){
          app.router.navigate('/new', true);
          return false;
        }
      });

      //Define the Application Router
      app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({ 
        routes: {
          "": "contacts",
          "contacts":"contacts",
          "new": "newContact",
          ":id": "contact"
        },          
        contacts: function() {
          var contactsCollection = new app.ContactsCollection();
          $.mobile.loading( "show", { text: 'Loading Contacts', textVisible: true } );
          contactsCollection.fetch({success: function(){
            $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
            $("#contacts-content").html(new app.ContactsView({model: contactsCollection}).el);
            // Let jQuery Mobile do its stuff
            $("#contacts-content").trigger( 'create' );
            $.mobile.changePage( "#contacts" , { reverse: false, changeHash: false } );
          }});
        },
        contact: function(id) {
          var contact = new app.Contact({Id: id});
          $.mobile.loading( "show", { text: 'Loading Contact', textVisible: true } );
          contact.fetch({success: function(){
            $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
            $("#contact-content").html(new app.ContactDetailView({model: contact}).el);
            $("#contact-content").trigger( 'create' );
            $.mobile.changePage( "#contact" , { reverse: false, changeHash: false } );
          }});
        },
        newContact: function(id) {
          var contact = new app.Contact();
          $("#contact-content").empty();
          $("#contact-content").html(new app.ContactDetailView({model: contact}).el);
          $("#contact-content").trigger( 'create' );
          $.mobile.changePage( "#contact" , { reverse: false, changeHash: false } );
        }
      });

      app.router = new app.Router();
      Backbone.history.start();
    }
  </script>

</body>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visualforce Remote Objects for accessing any SObjects from JS. For instance, you can define some objects on Visualforce page

```
<apex:remoteObjects >
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Warehouse__c" jsShorthand="Warehouse" fields="Name,Id">
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="Phone__c" jsShorthand="Phone"/>
    </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

And then work with these objects right in JavaScript:

```
<script>
    fetchWarehouses = function(){
        // Create a new Remote Object
        var wh = new SObjectModel.Warehouse();

        // Use the Remote Object to query for 10 warehouse records
        wh.retrieve({ limit: 10 }, function(err, records){
            if(err) alert(err.message);
            else {
                var ul = document.getElementById("warehousesList");
                records.forEach(function(record) {
                    // Build the text for a warehouse line item
                    var whText = record.get("Name");
                    whText += " -- ";
                    whText += record.get("Phone");

                    // Add the line item to the warehouses list
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(whText));
                    ul.appendChild(li);
                });
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

For more information see [SF documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects.htm).